# Direct Object or Complement or Something else

Tags: syntactic-analysis, complements

```
She failed to respond.
She wanted to smile.
She decided to return.
She preferred to travel by train.
She managed to save a little money.
```

Are the infinitival clauses complements or direct objects in these sentences? Are they complements in the last two sentences and direct objects in others?

Comment: +1 Nice question. However, a direct object is just one type of complement. So if it's a direct object, it *is* a complement!

Comment: A test for direct object is whether it can be made subject of a passive. "To travel by train was preferred."

Comment: @GregLee Is it always the case? Some verbs don't have a passive counterpart.

Comment: @KaptanSingh, passivization is always a test, but a direct object might fail the test because, as you point out, the verb doesn't allow the passive form.  The "have" of possession is like that.  There can be other reasons why a direct object fails. That's the way tests work -- or don't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to various grammars you will get various answers. The infinitive after a verb can be seen as an object. The simplest and clearest way to describe this verb construction is verb + to-infinitive. It does not matter much what special term you use for the infinitive part. In any case the term infinitive-clause is not appropriate as a clause contains a subject and a finite verb form.

Comment: Give evidence..